# Does 外地人 include those who were born outside but grew up inside?

Tags: word

Suppose that a Shanghainese husband and Hangzhounese wife gave birth to their child at a hospital in Chengdu, but raised the child in Shanghai (from age 0 to 18).

In this case, is the child still considered 上海人 or 外地人 in Shanghai? Or is the child considered 成都人 since it is the place of the birth, even if he or she didn't come again to 成都 after the birth? And how about the child whose parents are both NOT shanghainese but he or she grew up in Shanghai (e.g. if the husband is Hangzounese is the child also considered Hangzhounese?)

[百度百科](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%A4%96%E5%9C%B0%E4%BA%BA/10798295?fr=aladdin) doesn't seem to mention it...

Comment: also see discussion of 籍贯 （the permanent place of residence of someone's great-grandfather and paternal ancestors ）  https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%B1%8D%E8%B4%AF

Comment: Like technically or just based off of the scope of 外地人? I think 外地人 is more like ones ability to 融入 rather than anything else. Most people wouldn't give a rats about technicalities if you can really *fit in*. Again if you're really from a place but don't act like it, people are more likely to think of you as an outsider.

Comment: If a Chinese couple gives birth to a child in your country (thus granting the child citizenship of that country in some jurisdictions) and then grow him/her in China until their 18. Do you consider them a **foreigner**? I think the answer depends very much on the context.

Comment: @zypA13510 It doesn't depend on the context at all. Your example focuses on the foreign countries but my question is all about "within China". So the only possible way to make the answer "depend on the context" is if people from each province think it differently (which could be possible).

Comment: @user3306356 Technically. I agree with your second point, but then it gets highly dependent on each person.

Comment: @Blaszard I think it would get very cliché and quite stereotypical. You're dealing with people who only care about "*standard* answers", though, so it's not quite unexpected.

Comment: @Blaszard My example is all about "countries on Earth" while yours is all about "provinces in China" :) Now think carefully, what is the real difference between a country, and a province? They are both a geographical area **defined by human**, both with its unique **culture** that separates each other while not completely independent, both with the idea of **citizenship** (Hukou). Remember, each province in China is probably larger than a country in Europe, so the difference is probably larger than what separates those countries.

Answer (score 1):

Different people may take this differently. Based on my observation, from a traditional Shanghainese perspective, the criteria of 上海本地人 are:

1. 户口 is registered in Shanghai.
2. Live in Shanghai starting from the very early ages.
3. Able to communicate in Shanghai dialect.
4. Understand the tradition of Shanghai.
5. Your parents are Shanghainese (this criteria may not be that strict. )

It sounds *bias*, but that's the reality I think.

Answer (score 0):

> Most important of all: unlike 土生上海人 (native Shanghainese), any permanent resident of Shanghai is considered 上海人

A person is considered 本地人 if he was born and/or raised in that place and is a long time permanent resident.

A person is considered 外地人 if he was not born or raised in that place and is not a permanent resident.

If a person was born and/or raise in that place, lived elsewhere for a long time then come back to take up permanent residency, he is still considered 本地人 (local) or  土生 (native)

If a person was born and/or raised in that place, lived elsewhere for a long time then come back for a visit, he is neither 本地人 nor 外地人. He is a 回鄉客

If a person was born and raised elsewhere, but is a long time permanent resident, he is certainly not a 外地人. Depend on how much he adapted to the local culture, he can be considered 本地人 (local) or 老移民 (long time immigrant)

> *Suppose that a Shanghainese husband and Hangzhounese wife gave birth to their child at a hospital in Chengdu, but raised the child in Shanghai (from age 0 to 18).
>   In this case, is the child still considered 上海人 or 外地人 in Shanghai?*

Since he is a permanent resident, he is considered 上海人 in Shanghai.
Since he was raised in Shanghai, he is also considered a 本地人 (local)